# Git - creating snapshots of parameter updates

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am currently new to Git, and have a very basic working knowledge on Git. I see the potential of using this, but currently unsure on the path to take for my query below.

> Background:

I have a source code/master code which remains relatively unchanged over long periods of time. However, at the end of every month, I take the Source code, do many manual “parameter” updates – for example: date, flags, user_id, dataset name, dataset filters, etc. and run the Source code. (see image)
[image]

> What I need:

I want to save an instance of the new "parameters" settings at every snapshot. The parameter settings (eg. date, dataset name, begin date, end date, etc.) are manually entered into the "main" program which calls the source code. This is required should someone request a historical code run. For example:: If today (July 2018), someone requests to reproduce data as of Feb/2018, then all I want to do is revert to the “Parameter” settings as of Feb/2018 and run the code.

The Parameter changes should and will not be merged back into the source code, even if it’s a bug fix/Hot fix / additional development. However, noting the differences in “parameter” updates between every snapshot would be good.

What would be your best way to approach this problem and what commands would you use? – A stepwise “git” command procedure would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your source code separate from your parameter settings, I would store the values in a separate config file. For example:

```
./src
  ./<all your source code>
./conf
  ./parameters.conf
```

And, if you want to keep track of changes to the parameters, you will have to commit the config file along with your source code to the git repo.

For each snapshot, you will update the conf file with the new values, and then commit it back to the repo:

```
git add conf/parameters.conf
```

And then you can [tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) the commit, so that it can be retreived in the future:

```
git tag -a snapJun2018 -m "Snapshot for June 2018"
git push --tags origin
```

You can then retreive a historical snapshot using the tag name:

```
git checkout snapJun2018
```

And list all tagged commits:

```
git tag
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to revision your input data you have to provide them in a "revisionable" way. This means they need to be serialized into a file that can be checked in into git.

If that requirement is met I'd create a branch for every "run" with that "parameter file" being the only change:

```
a - b - f - g - h- i -> master
    \-  c -> run1   \-  j -> run4
     \- d -> run2    k ->    run5
      e ->  run3
```